# How to get Change due to customer c#

Tags: c#, winforms, int, currency

[image]Hi guys iam trying to create a payment form in which will have the total price of the order, the amount paid, and the change due to customer (all in textboxes). this is what I have so far, not sure if I am on the right track or not. nothing seems to be being added in the change textbox, and the amount paid(tendered) textbox is not adding the numbers it is adding like 5 + 5 = 55. PS.

```
 private string GetChange(int Tendered, int Cost, string Change)
    {
        Tendered = int.Parse( TxtbxTendered.Text);
        Cost = int.Parse(TxtbxDue.Text);
        Change = Convert.ToString((Tendered - Cost));
        TxtbxChange.Text = Change;
        MessageBox.Show(Change , "Oops", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return Change;  
    }


    private void Picbx5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // picbox5 represents $5 cash
    {
        TxtbxDue.Text = Convert.ToString(Decimal.Parse(TxtbxDue.Text) - value5); //Takes away Value from amount due
        TxtbxTendered.Text = Convert.ToString(value5);
    }
```

Comment: You add `string`s, unlike integers, decimal etc `5 + 5 == 10` strings concatenate: `"5" + "5" == "55"`

Comment: Don't go on a "Convert/Parse" rampage. Use a model that's based on numerical data. Only format to string for Display.

Comment: Why do you have input parameters at all in this method?

Comment: Shouldn't the method signature be `private int GetChange(int Tendered, int Cost)`?